# is it possible to have nonlocal in python lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, closures

right now my lambda function is :

```
In [40]: f=lambda x, count=0: count if not(x%3==0) else count+1

In [41]: [f(x) for x in range(10)]
Out[41]: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

But what I really want is to accumulate the count, so that the output would be:

```
Out[42]: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

I am looking for some code like:

```
f=lambda x, count=0: nonlocal count if not(x%3==0) else count+1
```

but got a syntax error message for the use of "nonlocal". So my question is: is there a way to define nonlocal variable in lambda?

Comment: A function parameter can never be `global` or `nonlocal`.

Comment: Why not just create a named function with `def`?

Comment: How would `nonlocal` help? That's only meaningful for variables that you assign to, but you can't do variable assignments in a lambda (although I think there are some tricks using the walrus operator).

Comment: I feel like you're falling prey to the [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if you just want to accumulate the count `[(x // 3 )+ 1 for x in range(10)]` something like this will work as well

Comment: use `itertools.accumulate`

Comment: Thanks for all comments. The code shown here is just an example; my real question is how to realize the function of nonlocal (or a closure) in lambda.

Comment: The simple answer is you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, lambda functions should be *pure functions*, that is why they are **purposefully restricted to expressions**.

As such, you cannot assign to a nonlocal/global variable in a lambda expression (although, you can use assignment expressions to assign to local variables).

If you *want* to use `nonlocal`/`global` and *assign* to a variable, you can *always just use a function definition statement*. You never *have* to use a lambda expression to create a function. And lambda expressions are purposefully restricted in their capabilities. If you want something beyond that, just use a function definition statement.

But in this case, you *shouldn't do that* In this case, you are trying to use a list-comprehension for side-effects. This is generally confusing and considered an anti-pattern. It is better to simply use a for-loop:

```
result = []
count = 0
for i in range(10):
    if i%3 == 0:
        count += 1
    result.append(count)
```

This is perfectly pythonic.

But if you wanted a more functional programming approach, you should use `itertools.accumulate`:

```
import itertools
result = itertools.accumulate(map(lambda x: int(x%3 == 0), range(10)))
```

Lambda expression cannot contain statements like `nonlocal` or `global`. But you should choose the right tool for the job, and in this case, it is either just a normal for-loop, or `itertools.accumualte`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use a lambda function to do so, you can try this:

```
count = 0
f = lambda x: (setattr(f, 'count', getattr(f, 'count', 0) + 1) if x % 3 == 0 else None, f.count)[1]

print([f(x) for x in range(10)])
```

I'd advise agains it though. The guys have given you some better options than lambda...